# Need Help Converting JQuery .delegate to .live

Tags: jquery

I am working on script where I have code like this...

```
$(document).delegate(scroll.links,'click',function(){
            switchTo(getId(this.href))
            return false
        })
```

I want to convert it into .live I tried but couldnt get it right.

Can anybody show me ?

Thanks.

Comment: You are crazy to bind it `document` unless you can't find something closer to your `scroll.links`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
$('scroll.links').live('click', function(){
   switchTo(getId(this.href));
   return false;
});
```

However, it is important to know the difference between the two:

- [Difference between delegate and live](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-the-difference-between-live-and-delegate/)

Comment: @MANnDAaR: *Not working*. Can you elaborate little more what happens? Any error message there?

Comment: My Mistake.. I wrote it wrong.. Now Its Working fine . Thank You so much.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the docs, I imagine it would be something like this:

```
$(scroll.links).live("click", function() {
    switchTo(getId(this.href))
    return false
})
```

**Note: I have not tested this.** I successfully use `delegate()` in some of my own code; the docs suggest that `delegate()` is actually more powerful and more flexible.